# Using JavaScript variable in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some JavaScript here:

```
<script>
    function random(n) {
        return ((Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(n)))+1);
    }


var x = random(5000)+2000;
</script>
```

I also have some CSS:

```
<style>


.fadingVariable{animation:fading 7s infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}20%{opacity:1}50%{opacity:1}80%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}


</style>
```

The CSS is essentially fading an image in and out every 7 seconds.  I'd like that time unit to be variable, like var x in my JavaScript.  How do I do that?  I assume I can't just do:

```
<style>


.fadingVariable{animation:fading 'x's infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}20%{opacity:1}50%{opacity:1}80%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}


</style>
```

Comment: Take a look at LESS or SCSS. It is just like CSS but with functions and variables

Answer (score 1):

You can't really set the variable IN the CSS, but you can apply the style directly to the element using JS:

`document.getElementById('myEl').style.animation = 'fading ' + x + 's infinite');`

Or if you want to apply it to every element with that class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fadingVariable').forEach(el => {
    el.style.animation = 'fading ' + x + 's infinite';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I don't quite understand how to implement what you've suggested.  I assume it should go in my script, but how am I to use it?  This is my attempt:

    document.getElementsByClassName('carouselTwo').forEach(el => {el.style.animation = 'fading ' + 3 + 's infinite';});
    
    <div id="carouselTwo" style="position: top:0px;left:0px;">

Comment: That should do it if `carouselTwo` is the class of element you want to apply the animation to, and yes, this should be part of your script. Bear in mind that if your script is in the `head` of your HTML and you fire this before the dom is loaded, it won't be able to find the elements. Either do this in a script at the end of the `body` or only fire this on `DOMContentLoaded` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Thank you, it's nearly working.  Images are switching at random times, but the fade time remains at 7 seconds, resulting in some images not fading out properly.  Some images last for 5 seconds, which is less than the fade time, meaning that they fade in properly, but disappear before being able to fade out.  How do I randomize the fade time along with my variable, x, within my script?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the duration property using javascript and the rest of properties using css like this:
javascript code :

```
var x = 7;
document.getElementById('fadingVariable').style.animationDuration = x + 's';
```

css code :

```
.fadingVariable{animation:fading infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}20%{opacity:1}50%{opacity:1}80%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}
```

notice that got rid of the duration property in css code.
hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about IE (at the time of writing), you could look into the new [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

```
:root {
    --fade-interval: 7s;
}

.fadingVariable {
    animation: fading var(--fade-interval) infinite
}
@keyframes fading {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    20% { opacity: 1 }
    50% { opacity: 1 }
    80% { opacity: 1 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Otherwise, a CSS preprocessor like SASS or SCSS would let you set up such variables easily to be compiled to CSS.